# previous_post_link/next_post_link disappear when excluding by post_format

Tags: post-formats, register-taxonomy

I am trying to exclude aside post formats from my next and previous links, but for some reason, using `get_term_by` is not returning me the `term_id` for the `post_format` taxonomy.  I see this taxonomy being used by the Wordpress core [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-formats.php#L141), so I know I'm doing this the right way.  According to [this posting](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats), I need to be sure that the taxonomy is properly registered.  Print debugging I see the following output from `get_taxonomies()`.

```
Array
(
    [category] => category
    [post_tag] => post_tag
    [nav_menu] => nav_menu
    [link_category] => link_category
    [post_format] => post_format
    [tagportfolio] => tagportfolio
)
```

So I can see the `post_format` taxonomy has been registered.  Here is my code:

```
<?php print_r(get_taxonomies()); ?>
<?php print_r(get_term_by('id', 'post-format-aside', 'post_format')->term_id); ?>
<?php previous_post_link('&lsaquo; %link', '%title', false, array(get_term_by('id', 'post-format-aside', 'post_format')->term_id )); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link &rsaquo;', '%title', false, array(get_term_by('id', 'post-format-aside', 'post_format')->term_id )); ?>
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working?  Why aren't the aside posts being excluded here?

**UPDATE 1**

The following code gives me back a term_id from `get_term_by`, but causes the next/previous links to disappear:

```
<?php print_r(get_taxonomies()); ?>
<?php print_r(get_term_by('slug', 'post-format-aside', 'post_format')->term_id); ?>
<?php previous_post_link('&lsaquo; %link', '%title', false, array(get_term_by('slug', 'post-format-aside', 'post_format')->term_id )); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link &rsaquo;', '%title', false, array(get_term_by('slug', 'post-format-aside', 'post_format')->term_id )); ?>
```

The object returned by `get_term_by` is:

```
STDCLASS OBJECT ( [TERM_ID] => 10 [NAME] => ASIDE [SLUG] => POST-FORMAT-ASIDE [TERM_GROUP] => 0 [TERM_TAXONOMY_ID] => 10 [TAXONOMY] => POST_FORMAT [DESCRIPTION] => [PARENT] => 0 [COUNT] => 0 [FILTER] => RAW )
```

**UPDATE 2**

When I enable the [Wordpress query debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#SAVEQUERIES), I see the following query being triggered, which is the empty set.

```
mysql> SELECT P.ID FROM WP_POSTS AS P INNER JOIN WP_TERM_RELATIONSHIPS AS TR ON P.ID = TR.OBJECT_ID INNER JOIN WP_TERM_TAXONOMY TT ON TR.TERM_TAXONOMY_ID = TT.TERM_TAXONOMY_ID WHERE P.POST_DATE < '2015-06-01 20:10:00' AND P.POST_TYPE = 'PROJECT' AND TT.TAXONOMY = 'CATEGORY' AND P.ID NOT IN ( SELECT TR.OBJECT_ID FROM WP_TERM_RELATIONSHIPS TR LEFT JOIN WP_TERM_TAXONOMY TT ON (TR.TERM_TAXONOMY_ID = TT.TERM_TAXONOMY_ID) WHERE TT.TERM_ID IN (10) ) AND ( P.POST_STATUS = 'PUBLISH' OR P.POST_STATUS = 'PRIVATE' ) ORDER BY P.POST_DATE DESC ;

Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

What's strange about the above is that the query appears to be attempting to find the previous post based on the category taxonomy, which I have explicitly asked the function not to do through the query parameters.  This seems like a bug in Wordpress to me.

Comment: The `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link` much take  Array or a comma-separated list of numeric terms IDs for the `excluded_terms` i.e. the 4th parameter

Comment: Fair enough. But why does `get_term_by('id', 'post-format-aside', 'post_format')->term_id` return nothing in this case when there are aside posts in the database?

Comment: `get_term_by` will take either  'id', 'slug', 'name', or 'term_taxonomy_id' which you already know but when your 1st paramert is `id` your 2nd parameter must be the taxonomy id which is probably a number. [Read Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

Comment: @Karun Thanks! get_term_by now returns a term_id, but strangely, the above code causes the next and prev links to be blank. Thoughts?

Comment: May be the `get_term_by` returned all ids making the pagination blank. Check the ids returned by the function. I think there is no post to be displayed next or previous.

Comment: @Karun Updated the post. The only term returned is for `term_id` 10.  So I am passing `array(10)` to the `$excluded_terms` parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25309/discussion-between-karun-and-markshiz).

Comment: What is your php version

Comment: Also, what happens if you just pass `array(10)` to the parameter

Comment: @PieterGoosen Passing array(10) results in the links disappearing as well.  PHP version is 5.4.38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug against Wordpress as the query here leads me to believe that this is a bug in the framework: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32833#ticket